# JBoss Drools checks conditions once

Tags: java, jboss, rules, drools

I have implemented Drools into my Java Project. All the rules fire but the conditions only get checked once immediately after being fired.

Is this the way Drools behaves? I need it to be constantly checking a boolean for any changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how a forward-chaining rule engine behaves (which is extremely efficient).

If your fact changes (so if the result of it's boolean property/method changes), the rule engine should be notified by `workingMemory.updated(fact, factHandle)`. The rule engine will then fire all the rules (and not a single rule more) which need to be fired based on that change.

[Here's a diagram to explain why this can make your app a lot more scalable because it has to run a lot less code.](http://www.slideshare.net/ge0ffrey/pushing-the-rule-engine-to-its-limits-with-drools-planner-parisjug-20101109/37)

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Geoffrey De Smet. You need to update the session with the latest facts. Or You can use "no-loop" attribute. When the rule's consequence modifies a fact it will cause the Rule to activate again, causing recursion.